# What is the purpose of rcsshd?

Tags: ssh, opensuse, sshd

I'm starting up an SSH server on a fresh OpenSUSE Leap virtual machine, and I found that the documentation tells me to use `rcsshd` to start the server.

I can't find a `man` page or really any documentation on `rcsshd`, nor does the `--help` option tell me anything. I can see it manages many other services.. is this kind of like `systemctl` (a service manager) in OS X and it just happens to be named after `sshd`?

What is the purpose of `rcsshd` and why can't I just use `sshd` directly?

Comment: Which documentation is telling you this?

Comment: @DopeGhoti https://en.opensuse.org/SDB:Configure_openSSH https://en.opensuse.org/SDB:OpenSSH_basics

Comment: I'd be inclined to look at `rcsshd`, wherever it is, and look to see if it's just a confabulated wrapper for `/etc/init.d/sshd` or `service sshd $verb`.

Comment: @DopeGhoti after taking a look, your hunch seems to be pretty spot on.. seems to just be a shell script wrapper on `systemd`, `systemctl`, etc. I'm still not sure why it's called `rcsshd` in that case though, or why the documentation tells us to use it instead of just plain old `sshd`, or why it even exists in the first place if we could just use `systemctl`. Nice insight/intuition. I figured only binaries would be under `/usr/sbin`.

Answer (score 0):

`/usr/sbin/rcsshd` is a symlink to the `service` binary that considers the name under which it is called.

One advantage is that you get tab-completion in the shell.

Also `rcsshd` and `service` worked the same way before systemd came to be, so if you used these in scripts or docs, they kept working (especially important when you have a mix of old and new OSes).